# Pass json result to sencha touch

Tags: java, json, sencha-touch, restful-architecture

I am new for sencha touch. I need to pass json data by using RESTful architectural .But I dun has any Idea how to start it.Can anyone guild me some example? Btw I am using JACKSON library.

Here is my java file - jsonTest.java

```
    package jsonTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;



import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonEncoding;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.TypeReference;



public class jsonTest {

      private static List<String> countries;
        private static List<String> tags;

         public static void main(String[] args) {

            String data = "Afghanistan, Albania, Algeria, Andorra, Angola, Antigua & Deps,"+ 
                    "United Kingdom,United States,Uruguay,Uzbekistan,Vanuatu,Vatican City,Venezuela,Vietnam,Yemen,Zambia,Zimbabwe";

            countries = new ArrayList<String>();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data, ",");

            //Parse the country CSV list and set as Array
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                countries.add(st.nextToken().trim());
            }

            String strTags = "SharePoint, Spring, Struts, Java, JQuery, ASP, PHP, JavaScript, MySQL, ASP, .NET";
            tags = new ArrayList<String>();
            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(strTags, ",");

            //Parse the tags CSV list and set as Array
            while(st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
                tags.add(st2.nextToken().trim());
            }

        }

        public List<String> getCountryList(String query) {

            String country = null;
            query = query.toLowerCase();
            List<String> matched = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0; i < countries.size(); i++) {
                country = countries.get(i).toLowerCase();
                if(country.startsWith(query)) {
                    matched.add(countries.get(i));
                }
            }
            return matched;
        }

        public List<String> getTechList(String query) {
            String country = null;
            query = query.toLowerCase();
            List<String> matched = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0; i < tags.size(); i++) {
                country = tags.get(i).toLowerCase();
                if(country.startsWith(query)) {
                    matched.add(tags.get(i));
                }
            }
            return matched;
        }

}
```

How can I show the result to my sencha touch project?By using list or panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) for developing the web service. Specifically, as I have worked with Jersey, it supports POJO Mapping i.e. your web service can return a POJO (Plain Old Java Object) which Jersey can implicitly convert into JSON.

Here's a working example from mkyong's website for [POJO](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/) Mapping and [JSON with Jersey](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/).

**PS**: I have no experience in working with sencha Touch and hence can't help much with that.

Comment: hi, thanks for ur answer. i try the example. But i get the error HTTP Status 404 - /RestfulExample/json/product/get

Comment: Did you make appropriate entries in `web.xml`? Are you using the entire source code provided for download?

Comment: Additionally, you need to deploy the war on tomcat? Are you doing this?

Comment: ya. i try using the example, wat u means? deploy the war on tomcat?sorry i am new for java

Comment: Ok you are missing few steps. Search for `Deploying war on tomcat` and `Installing tomcat` as well. Tomcat is an application server and you need to run your web service on that container.

Comment: Have a look at this [url](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/)